# Large padded areas between portions of a form?

Tags: html

I am using this code for a custom calculator on my site, but when it's live, there appears to be a large padded area between part I of the form and Part II of the form.

It's pretty simple code. I just can't get past the wide-open unused area the form uses.

```html
<div align="center"><p>How many miles from Petersburg, Virginia are you?</p>
<form oninput="x.value= Math.round(a.value*b.value)+(c.value*d.value)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="" maxlength="3">
<input type="hidden" id="b" value="0.60"><br>
<p>And, how many pages require a notary seal?</p><br>
<input type="number" id="c" value="" maxlength="3">
<input type="hidden" id="d" value="3"><br>
<i>Your quote:</i><font color="green"><big>$<output name="x" for="a b c d"></big></font></output></form></form>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked the margins the `<p>` element adds?

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

```
<p>And, how many pages require a notary seal?</p><br>
```

you have a `<p>` and a `<br>`. The `<p>` tag has margin top and bottom and is a block element so it covers the whole width. The `<br>` is adding extra space by forcing another line break. Remove the `<br>`.

Comment: I actually discovered that typo minutes after I asked the question. But your answer is dead-on target - great instruction as well.